# Android application crashes when performing an if statement?

Tags: android, crash, integer

I have no idea why my Android application is crashing. I noticed it happened when I put in the simple firstTime variable, but I'm honestly clueless to why the firstTime variable would make the whole application crash. Every other part works if I take out the if statement. This is what I have put in so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static int firstTime = 0;
BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if(firstTime == 0){
        logTime(false);
        firstTime++;
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON); 
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF); 
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
          if(arg1.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
            logTime(true);
          }
          else if(arg1.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
            logTime(false);
          }
        } 
      }; 
      registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

}
```

Might anyone know why the firstTime variable crashes my application? thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see your issue now. Move the if after `setContentView()`. With your current code the textView will be `null` and throw an NPE.

Comment: @A--C post as an answer please, not a comment.

Comment: @JasonRobinson Thanks for the advice :-) You're the first person who isn't the question's OP telling me to do that. I just wasn't sure if I was right, so I refrained from making an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't think of this before, I was thinking you wanted to just increment the `int`, so I wasn't thinking about calling `logTime()` again, and didn't see how it could crash with such a simple concept.

Your issue is *most* likely the order, since with your current code the `textView` in the method will be `null` and will throw an NPE when accessed.

This is because the `findViewById()` in `logTime()` will return `null` (a content view isn't set - so there isn't anything to find):

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 if(firstTime == 0){
    logTime(false);
    firstTime++;
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks. Just one last question... you see when I load my Android application twice, logtime prints twice... I have no idea why... might you know? Sorry to bother with so many questions!

Comment: *I load my Android application twice* please elaborate. Load as in tap from the home screen? Do you explicitly press the back button?

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. I accidently added in an onResume function. Thank you for your help! I really really appreciate it!